# What would be the right way to call changeIsSavedStatus() just once every time a fetch request in the action fails/ throws error?

Tags: react-native, redux, fetch, dispatch

What would be the right way to call changeIsSavedStatus() just once every time a fetch request in the action fails/ throws error?

```
removeSavedDeals = () => {
    this.changeIsSavedStatus();

    //This Statement makes a fetch request and sets removeSelectedSavedDeals_ErrorStatus to true if error occurs
    this.props.removeSelectedSavedDeals([this.props.navigation.getParam("dealDetails")._id], this.props.savedDealsListDataSource);

    //This changeIsSavedStatus() statement does not gets executed as this.props.removeSelectedSavedDeals_ErrorStatus is still false when the if statement is executed.
    if(this.props.removeSelectedSavedDeals_ErrorStatus){
        changeIsSavedStatus();
    }
}

changeIsSavedStatus=()=>{
    this.setState({
        isSaved:!this.state.isSaved
    })
}
```

removeSelectedSavedDeals Action

```
export const removeSelectedSavedDeals = (dealIdToUnSave, dataSource) => dispatch => {
const toDelete = new Set(dealIdToUnSave);
const newDataSource = dataSource.filter(item => !toDelete.has(item._id));
//Send request to Backend to delete dealIdToUnSave from db
let url = sett.host+`/users/removeSavedDeals`;
return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        dealIdToUnSave: dealIdToUnSave,
        savedDealsListDataSource: newDataSource
    }),
})
.then((res) => {
    if (!res.ok) {
        console.log("Fake Error");
        throw Error(res.statusText);
    }
    return res;
})
.then(res => {
    dispatch({
        type: "removeSelectedSavedDeals_Success",
        newDataSource
    })
})
.catch(err => {
    //TODO: Handle Error Properly
    console.log("Error Encountered While Unsaving Deals: "+ err);
    dispatch({
        type: "removeSelectedSavedDeals_Error",
        err
    })
});
}
```

P.S. Also suggest if there is any way to improve my removeSavedDeals()

Answer (score 1):

If `props.removeSelectedSavedDeals` calls fetch, it should also return a promise. You can then run your `changeIsSavedStatus` in the catch of the promise.

```
removeSavedDeals = () => {
    this.changeIsSavedStatus();

    //This Statement makes a fetch request and sets removeSelectedSavedDeals_ErrorStatus to true if error occurs
    this.props.removeSelectedSavedDeals(...)
        .then(() => {...})
        .catch(err => {
            this.changeIsSavedStatus();
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. This did help. But I have one more question. When my the .catch statement in my fetch request gets executed, the .catch statement in the this.props.removeSelectedSavedDeals(...).then().catch() does not get executed. Rather .then of  this statement gets executed. I have updated my code to include my removeSelectedSavedDeals Action. Thanks

Comment: You could remove the catch from the `removeSelectedSavedDeals` call in which case it would be handled by the calling function above.